# Will the slope change for a line change if we change the origin from top-left to bottom-left?

Tags: ios, coordinate-systems

In my iphone app, I am required to draw a line between two points and display its slope.
now my calculations are simply based on.

`slope  =  (startPoint.y - endPoint.y) / (startPoint.x - endPoint.x )`

the startPoint and endPoint which I have are in terms of screen-pixel coordinates where origin is on top left corner.

but I am displaying this line over a graph where my axes are laid with coordinate system having origin on bottom-left corner on screen.

Will this affect the slope I am calculating ?
I have already taken care of converting x,y coordinates with respect to graph's x,y axes scale units.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not modifying startPoint.y or endPoint.y then the slope will be unchanged, but it won't match what is being drawn to the screen. Also, you will need to handle both x values being the same which will result in a division by zero error.

Comment: thanks .. but I just did a little math it seems i might get a -1 X slope, instead of slope.